# Having trouble figuring out how to get my 3d models to animate in Drei

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

Ive managed to get my 3D models only my application but cant for the life of me figure out how to play the animation.

Ive read the documentation and looked around the web this is what I got from documentation but it isn't in-depth enough and I don't know how to implement it

This is what I got from the documentation

```
const {
    nodes, materials, animations
} = useGLTF(url)
const {
    ref, mixer, names, actions, clips
} = useAnimations(animations)
useEffect(() = > {
    actions ? .jump.play()
})
return (
    <mesh ref={ref} />
```

This is what I have coded

```
import React from 'react'
import {useGLTFLoader,  } from 'drei';
function Model({ url }) {
  const gltf = useGLTFLoader(url, true);
  return <primitive animated={true} object={gltf.scene} dispose={null} />;
}

export default Model
```

Comment: Have you looked on codesandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/search?refinementList%5Bnpm_dependencies.dependency%5D%5B0%5D=%40react-three%2Fdrei&refinementList%5Bnpm_dependencies.dependency%5D%5B1%5D=%40react-three%2Ffiber&page=1&configure%5BhitsPerPage%5D=12&query=animation
You may also need to use gltfjsx in order to get the correct jsx for your component with pivot bones etc for animation